# R, about numeric and character type of data

Tags: r

Let `x=1:3`, `y=c("1","2","3")`

If I type `ls.str()`, R shows that:

```
x :  int [1:3] 1 2 3
y :  chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
```

`x` is a numeric and `y` is a character vector.
Thus, when I typed `x == y`, I expected the result to be FALSE FALSE FALSE, but surprisingly R shows TRUE TRUE TRUE. Why does this happen? Isn't character type of data and numeric type of data different?

Comment: Thanks! By the way do you know any websites where I can get further explanations about R automatically converting to simplest type of data?

Comment: @Jay What you said is very wrong: the opposite is true. The coersion is made to the _most expensive_ type and in this case `x` is coerced to `character` (which is more expensive than an integer) and not the other way around. According to your logic `1.2==1L` should give `TRUE`, since the `1.2` should be coerced to integer and then the comparison. Actually, the integer `1L` is coerced to `double` (more expensive).

Comment: @Jin Give a look at `?c`, `Details` section: `The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression`. That hierarchy is used in operations that needs the same type (as `==`).

Comment: If you want to compare `x`  and `y` and get `FALSE`, you could use identical. This: `identical(x, y)` compares the two vectors and gives you a single `FALSE`, this could be used to compare them element by element: `mapply(identical, num, str)`.